# Запуск angular приложения на heroku

Tags: angular, heroku, package.json

У меня возникла проблема, решение которой я не смог найти нигде. Когда я пытаюсь задеплоить приложение, мне выбивает ошибку

```
-----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
-----> Using buildpack: heroku/nodejs
-----> Node.js app detected
       
-----> Creating runtime environment
       
       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NODE_VERBOSE=false
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
       
-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  12.18.2
       engines.npm (package.json):   6.14.5
       
       Resolving node version 12.18.2...
       Downloading and installing node 12.18.2...
       npm 6.14.5 already installed with node
       
-----> Restoring cache
       - node_modules
       
-----> Installing dependencies
       Installing node modules
       
       > fsevents@1.2.13 install /tmp/build_4e62ead8/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/fsevents
       > node install.js
       
       
       Skipping 'fsevents' build as platform linux is not supported
       
       > fsevents@1.2.13 install /tmp/build_4e62ead8/node_modules/watchpack-chokidar2/node_modules/fsevents
       > node install.js
       
       
       Skipping 'fsevents' build as platform linux is not supported
       
       > core-js@3.8.3 postinstall /tmp/build_4e62ead8/node_modules/core-js
       > node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
       
       
       > @angular/cli@12.1.3 postinstall /tmp/build_4e62ead8/node_modules/@angular/cli
       > node ./bin/postinstall/script.js
       
       added 1470 packages in 40.494s
       
-----> Build
       Detected both "build" and "heroku-postbuild" scripts
       Running heroku-postbuild
       
       > adpanel2@0.0.0 heroku-postbuild /tmp/build_4e62ead8
       > ng build --configuration production
       
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 3
npm ERR! adpanel2@0.0.0 heroku-postbuild: `ng build --configuration production`
npm ERR! Exit status 3
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the adpanel2@0.0.0 heroku-postbuild script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.Mo2Ii/_logs/2021-07-23T08_25_28_729Z-debug.log
-----> Build failed
       
       We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
       
       If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
       https://help.heroku.com/
       
       Love,
       Heroku
       
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
 !     Push failed
```

Причем, package.json и подобные файлы я вообще не трогал во время разработки. Пробовал изменять package.json (с devDependebcies в dependebcies переставлял зависимости), изменял *package-lock.json*, *heroku-postbuild: 'ng build --prod'* - эту строку тоже редактировал - ничего не помогает.

Вот мой **package.json**

```
{
  "name": "adpanel2",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "heroku-postbuild": "ng build --configuration production"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~11.2.12",
    "@angular/common": "~11.2.12",
    "@angular/cli": "^12.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^11.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "~11.2.12",
    "@angular/core": "~11.2.12",
    "@angular/forms": "~11.2.12",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~11.2.12",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.2.12",
    "@angular/router": "~11.2.12",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "reset-css": "^5.0.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "typescript": "~4.1.5",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1102.11",
    "@angular/cli": "^12.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^11.2.14",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.1.5"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "12.18.2",
    "npm": "6.14.5"
  }
}
```

Буду очень благодарен за любую помощь!

Answer (score 0):

```
Попробуй при диплое на heroku 
1. не ставить авто диплой!
2. Procfile web: node app.js
3. "postinstall": "ng build --aot --prod"
4."start": "node app.js",
5.  "engines": {
    "node": "14.16.1",
    "npm": "6.14.12"
  },
```